# Add no carrinho com Ajax sem atualizar a página - Laravel

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

Estou tentando usar Ajax em um form para adicionar produtos no carrinho sem atualizar a página mas não estou conseguindo, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Estou usando Laravel 5.3 baseado [neste site](http://davidtrushkov.com/store/):

HTML

```
<form id="form_ideal" action="/cart/add" method="post" name="add_to_cart">
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{$product->id}}" />
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1" />
<span class="compr-games" title="Add to Cart"><button class="btn-add-to-cart"> Buy Now </button></span>
</form>
```

Script que estou tentando:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#form_ideal').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/cart/add',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(msg) {
                swal('Test')
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

O que acontece é que ao clicar no botão de add ao carrinho ele mostra a mensagem de sucesso mas não atualiza a quantidade no menu, fica "0", só atualiza depois que dou F5 na página,

Desculpa se tiver fazendo algo errado mas comecei a pouco tempo a mexer com Laravel, ajax, essas coisas..

Answer (score -1):

Se você atualiza e aparece quer dizer que você já implementou essa função, então é só passar essa quantidade para o `client`, para atualizar carrinho com o método `html` do `J-query`, exemplo...

**em /cart/add devolva a quantidade assim.**

```
$retorno = array('quantidade' => $quantidadeNoCarrinho, 'msg' => 'sucesso!');
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

**em success pegue essa quantidade**

```
success: function(retorno) {
                alert(retorno.msg);
                $('.quantidade').html(retorno.quantidade)
                }
```

Comment: Olá Felipe, esse primeiro código eu coloco no controller? e o segundo no script? Desculpe como eu disse comecei a pouco tempo e não entendo muito ainda, Obrigado

Comment: O primeiro é no php, um simples echo, apontando um json, o segundo é j-query, repare que é uma parte do seu código já pronto só fiz umas modificações.